# Order by second Dimesion of String Array in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

We Have 2 dimensional string array like

```
"0" => {"John","23"},
"1" => {"Doe","12"},
"2" => {"Maria","41"},
 .......
```

We want to sort this array like

```
 "0" => {"Maria","41"},
 "1" => {"John","23"},
 "2" => {"Doe","12"},
     .......
```

Our Array Code  `String[,] kelimedeger = new String[20, 2];`

We want order by `kelimedeger[i,1]`

Comment: Why don't you start using classes? For example: `var kelimedeger=new List<User>{new User{Age=41, Name="Maria"}}`

Comment: @TimSchmelter I guess [multi-dimensional array sorting is popular today](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47505983/5265292). Though it might be a completely different background.

Comment: @TimSchmelter We can prefer it could you please explain how we can sort this list by age?

Comment: @MahirTahaÖzdin: `kelimedeger=kelimedeger.OrderBy(u=>u.Age).ToList()` or `kelimedeger.Sort((u1, u2) => u1.Age.CompareTo(u2.Age));`

Comment: @TimSchmelter we have a for loop that adds all users one by one where we going to define var kelimedeger and where we can add users one by one thanks <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Regarding Sorting

One of the problems I see here is that your second "string" is actually not a string, but rather a number. As such, you actually have a person with a name and an age.

### Why does this matter?

Sorting depends on the types of data. Strings are sorted alphabetically, while numbers are sorted numerically.

Consider the following list:

```
1, 2, 17, 11, 100, 20, 34
```

This can be sorted in multiple ways

```
Numerical    Alphabetical
---------    ------------
1            1
2            100
11           11
17           17
20           2
34           20
100          34
```

Given that you will most likely want to sort numerically, you need to store your data as `int`, not as `string`.

---

## How to store the data?

This depends on your use-case. If names are guaranteed to be unique, then you could use a `Dictionary<string,int>`. Otherwise, I advise you to create a class `Person` and use a `ICollection<Person>` to store them.

### As `Dictionary<string, int>`

This approach is useful if names are guaranteed to be unique in your domain. Further, it only uses built-in types.

```cs
namespace DictionaryTest
{
  public class Program
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      //Create a dictionary to store people
      Dictionary<string, int> people = new Dictionary<string, int>();

      //Add some people. Note that this is type-safe
      people.Add("John", 23);
      people.Add("Doe", 12);
      people.Add("Maria", 41);
      //people.Add("John", 55); // <-- This will fail because there is already a John

      //Create queries to ensure correct sorting
      var peopleByName = from p in people
                         orderby p.Key //Our name is the key, the age is the value
                         select new {Name = p.Key, Age = p.Value};

      var peopleByAge = from p in people
                        orderby p.Value
                        select new {Name = p.Key, Age = p.Value};

      var peopleByAgeDescending = from p in people
                                  orderby p.Value descending
                                  select new {Name = p.Key, Age = p.Value};

      //Execute the query and print results
      foreach(var person in peopleByAge)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, my name is {0} and I am {1} years old", person.Name, person.Age);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##pVRNb9swDL37VxA9JUASL916SjegS4Z9th2wojsMOzAykwiTJVeU0xmBf3tGf8TpurRoMcOwLfORfHwipXionKdtztou4VvBgdJJdHc1mjpjSAXtLI/ekyWv1T3EF21vJluLKXGGimCmazj64oo4RJsIIMvnRitQBpnhq3dLj6n8rkydkQMGea2dTuActe1x8JLlx09Av@R@DW0cAOJ46gkDAULSZYPgJIiUAxm5zFCL3dM5bSIOQNvwpgXBa7B0@xCo159EXcqzJAF26S78CC6cMAgrDPLQDHKHIqMh42KXu0WKZ@/ok1vZowEcv5SY/1pnjsQ4Pj5oPEevUcyvxp05jg/EPjnpT8QCp8MhXFWUbrUxsEBtYE4Kc67okggkJjSiYFKIgpVzdF/Ym1x2mrjSlCzn4iON4qURRAIfRKDWYY2@pfq2uJAWED0X3qWQiX5/78OBy/mE/LyAbPSZCsl9mXuo@qiWckXwi4pB/YHL7t8aTf5ISKaqW@s93bR86ugDOFs2i@sqQNnt690CGsiT@e/pXz9K6n85zYgV2aQaueeo@xBPSLp4T3B@Nvk4fvebVF6PRtNH0mQ2gUzGKoAnzk3gFruQaUW16jUFe3Z2X1hder8FbjqmUzmInPT9d68DydFDvaMPZIwbQFp0zbN5UdY5PwKmsBmXUBB6BmcSmZIm0agqpltUqXajVUa7ZxmV2@0f)

---

### As `ICollection<Person>`

This approach defines a class `Person`, which only holds a Name and an Age property, but can be extended to contain much more information, methods, etc.

```cs
namespace ClassTest
{
  public class Program
  {
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      //Create a list to store people
      ICollection<Person> people = new List<Person>();

      //Add some people. Note that this is type-safe
      people.Add(new Person(){ Name = "John", Age = 23, FavouriteColour = "Blue" });
      people.Add(new Person(){ Name = "Doe", Age = 12});
      people.Add(new Person(){ Name = "Maria", Age = 41, FavouriteColour = "Purple" });
      people.Add(new Person(){ Name = "John", Age = 55, FavouriteColour = "Gray" }); //<-- You can indeed have two people with the same name

      //Create queries to ensure correct sorting
      var peopleByName = from p in people
                         orderby p.Name
                         select p;

      var peopleByAge = from p in people
                        orderby p.Age
                        select p;

      var peopleByAgeDescending = from p in people
                                  orderby p.Age descending
                                  select p;


      //Execute the query and print results
      foreach(var person in peopleByAge)
      {
        Console.WriteLine("Hello, my name is {0} and I am {1} years old.", person.Name, person.Age);
        if(person.FavouriteColour != null)
        {
          Console.WriteLine("My favourite colour is {0}.", person.FavouriteColour);
        }
        else
        {
          Console.WriteLine("I have no favourite colour.");
        }
        Console.WriteLine(); //Add a new line for better readability
      }
    }
  }

  public class Person
  {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string FavouriteColour { get; set; }
  }
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nVVRb9owEH7Pr7jxFKRCR7c@0U1q6dZ1KlWlTZqmaQ9HcoAlx05thy6K8tvpOQlpClSCIQSJc/d9n33fXSI7iLShdWaFWsCP3DpKxkH3bjjRUlLkhFZ2eEOKjIi2Iu6EehyvFSZkU4wIJhKt/UnWBUUAkGYzKSKI/CI8GL0wmPCyf9Q@tA4d/620iGGKQoXWGSb48xfQLGy/Cq0TAE5PJ4bQESBIYR04zem8B0hJp5KaqNsX2RcPZKxWn5sA@ASKnuCOczdPwv44aNEv4xisTjZ4Q7jXTOaWyFRLYYG/Lk9pYHG@IWsiOTP00DVq2C/gns@E@Xrf9VL1TuBy4e/OPpzAV1zpzAhHLJMvfMyVzKgHJUs5EPRaU4s5OjsicYpGYJv6cbRXzkNmGOUoQa92eX6@F/bGYF6B8klfDAbwW2cQoQKhYqIYlrjis37Sm1o9CbfkYyewnsNbLNi2wWPGliTrfUDKZmwEdrTh0nMVjWMXNQkrNA3qVd4onhudQMrcr72z56NNTGaWQzr0qW/HWfKmg7T1U5e1PpiDSV84OTH4X8ZrshGp2LfrMRverwLiFu2A1I60tmhf/lGUVf1UVy4HVDGk3O0ODNlMOtvEzrmnMVqG9X681150VzvrN4FFK2XCM0qzRX95z/FUorD3jaTUJ5DklXl88xbvy4rzFjCBYlRCTmgsaBkP2bw1U1Xl9sZzjVsSMQ@b9W17v@PJkknZb0OLziHt0TbNYb6BYNNWGLXAjpItko6Qsr0iaelQ0tu6x5Te4R729oLvYlTN68ckVpNU8pqvFszIOTJcRoxxJqRwedAF879lsPNGqLa5@0Lw87@eLAUsyI3ZTfxTdoO8Z7wp3wxoULbrtB1fBuV6/Qw)

---

I personally like the second approach better, as it is more extendable and does not have a requirement for uniqueness of the name. It allows you to extend the `Person` class as much as you like, and gives you many more options for sorting.

Answer (score 0):

To sort a two-dimensional array you need to convert each row to a one-dimensional array and save it in a `List` or something similar. Then you can sort the list by the column. After sorting you need to convert the list back to a two-dimensional array.
Here is a method you could use for sorting:

```
public static T[,] Sort2DArray<T>(T[,] array, int column, bool ascending = true)
{
    int i = 0;
    List<T[]> items = new List<T[]>();

    int columns = array.GetLength(1);
    int rows = array.GetLength(0);

    T[] obj = new T[columns];
    foreach (var item in array)
    {
        obj[i % columns] = item;
        if ((i + 1) % 2 == 0)
        {
            items.Add(obj);
            obj = new T[columns];
        }

        i++;
    }

    var ordered = ascending ? items.OrderBy(a => a[column]) : items.OrderByDescending(a => a[column]);


    T[,] result = new T[rows, columns];
    for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++)
    {
        var row = ordered.ElementAt(r);
        for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++)
        {
            result[r, c] = row[c];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Your code would look like this:

```
string[,] array =
{
    {"John", "23" },
    {"Doe", "12" },
    {"Maria", "41" },
};

string[,] ordered = Sort2DArray(array, 1);//Sort by column 1 / Age
```

Converting a two-dimensional array to one- dimensional array and back is not the best routine to sort your values. The best way is to create a class to store your data, just as David Stockinger and Tim Schmelter said.